# I am trying to generate a csv file using mockaroo curl request but I am not getting whole 1000 records in the response. What could be the reason?

Tags: mocking, bigdata, data-science, automocking

I am trying curl command as `curl "https://api.mockaroo.com/api/2066ab40?count=1000&key=8bf92810" > sample.csv`. I want to get 1000 records in the sample.csv file, but I am getting only 4 records in the response as below.

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : id,first_name,last_name,email,gender
                    1,Travis,Durrans,tdurrans0@wikispaces.com,Male
                    2,Lucio,Purkins,lpurkins1@newyorker.com,Male
                    3,Kerianne,Hayne,khayne2@last.fm,Female
                    4,Sofie,Rosenblath,srosenbl...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
                    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
                    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                    Content-Disposition: attachment; fil...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Connection, keep-alive], [X-Frame-Options, SAMEORIGIN], [X-XSS-Protection, 1; mode=block]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 48646

    curl "https://api.mockaroo.com/api/2066ab40?count=1000&key=8bf92810" > sample.csv
```

Comment: what is after srosenbl... ?

Comment: @parladneupane, there is nothing after that in Content field.

Comment: The listed is the only response I am getting on the file.

Comment: I used the same request and I'm able to get all 1000 records